# Generate a JSON array of values for each row

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-13

Assuming the following CTE:

```sql
with mytable as (
    select column1 as foo, column2 as bar, column3 as baz
    from (values
      ('a', 'b', 1),
      ('c', 'd', 2)
    ) v
)
```

Using `array_agg()` ouputs an array of values:

```sql
select
    array_agg(v)
from mytable v;

-- {"(a,b,1)","(c,d,2)"}
```

but surprisingly (to me at least), using `to_json()` on this array restores the field names into an object for each row

```sql
select
    to_json(array_agg(v))
from mytable v;

-- [{"foo":"a","bar":"b","baz":1},{"foo":"c","bar":"d","baz":2}]
```

How can we make PostgreSQL output an array of arrays instead, rendering each row as an array of values?

```sql
select
    something(v)
from mytable v;

-- [["a", "b", 1],["c", "d", 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a row into a json, then unnest the key/value pairs and then aggregate the values back:

```
with mytable (foo, bar, baz) as (
  values
    ('a', 'b', 1),
    ('c', 'd', 2)
)
select jsonb_agg(x.vals)
from mytable m
  cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(value order by idx) as vals
    from json_each(row_to_json(m)) with ordinality as t(key,value,idx)
  ) x
```

It's important to use `json` to convert the row, if the order of the column values in the array is important for you.

If you need this often, you can put this into a function.

---

If the order of the column values in the array isn't important, you can use a JSON path function:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(to_jsonb(m), '$.keyvalue().value')
from mytable m;
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answer from a_horse_with_no_name, I just found a way to achieve this, assuming column names are known:

```sql
with mytable as (
    select column1 as foo, column2 as bar, column3 as baz
    from (values
      ('a', 'b', 1),
      ('c', 'd', 2)
    ) v
)

select
    to_json(array_agg(x.vals))
from (
    select
        json_build_array(
            v.foo,
            v.bar,
            v.baz
        ) as vals
    from mytable v
) x
;

-- [["a", "b", 1],["c", "d", 2]]
```